# ERROR: initcaps [Errno 2] iptables v1.6.0: can't initialize iptables table `filter': Table does not exist (do you need to insmod?)

Tags: linux, windows, bash, ssh

I ran into this issue (trying to solve another issue...) on my Windows Bash terminal.

```
ERROR: initcaps
[Errno 2] iptables v1.6.0: can't initialize iptables table `filter': Table does not exist (do you need to insmod?)
Perhaps iptables or your kernel needs to be upgraded.
```

What I'm trying to do is enable SSH access, so I can ssh into a linux server I made some time ago.

Scoured the net far and wide and literally *none* of the solutions work for me. Looks like most of the times people have experienced this has been on Docker containers, whereas I'm just using Windows.

```
sudo apt-get install linux-image-$(uname -r)
```

As well as various attempts to upgrade my kernel.

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get full-upgrade
```

Edit:
The root of the issue seems to be that I'm completely locked out of my Linux server through SSH.

Logging in through SSH via WSL won't let me in, and doing it through Putty or Git Bash causes me to run into a "connection timed out" problem.

Somehow I need to re-establish access to a server I've been locked out of SSH access too. The server is hosted on Linode.

Comment: WSL doesn't use iptables since it doesn't run a Linux kernel. What script are you running that's assuming iptables is available and loaded? Can you simply edit the script to ignore that step, and then set the corresponding *Windows* firewall rules using group policy manually?

Comment: Hi nanofarad, I am simply running `sudo ufw allow ssh`. This is so I can SSH into my linux server (which i could yesterday...). Strangely enough the app I'm hosting there runs just fine, but I'm completely locked out of being able to access the server. Edit: I have also tried running this same script with my computer's Firewall completely disabled.

Comment: `sudo ufw allow ssh` will not work if run *on* the Windows computer, and is irrelevant if your trouble is reaching a Linux server. You need to somehow obtain access to your Linux server (whether through some out of band means or otherwise) and run that command on the server.

Comment: @nanofarad, the conundrum here is that that's exactly the problem I'm trying to solve! Apparently installing nginx on it disabled SSH access, so now I'm completely locked out of it. I tried accessing it through Putty, and that didn't work as well. Pretty soul-crushing to think this could all have been avoided if i'd done that script after installing Nginx while I was still logged in on my Linux server!

Comment: You may want to log into the console of the provider that hosts that server -- they may provide out of band access, e.g. via a (virtualized) serial port, which should be enough to troubleshoot and recover SSH access. As for this post, I'd suggest editing it to better reflect the situation, as the current content is a bit misleading (since it refers to errors that occur when you run the script on your WSL machine)

Comment: Thanks a lot @nanofarad, finally fixed it with your guidance. Would you like to leave that comment as an Answer so I can accept it?

Comment: Your answer seems to stand on its own; I recommend accepting it instead (I also cannot add an answer as the question has been closed/put on hold because it doesn't quite fit the topic of Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 1):

Based on advice from @nanofarad, I did this, and it worked.

I went into the Linode console and launched the instance from there

[image: img]

Then, I clicked launch console, selected 'Glish', and then entered my username and password on the server, and then ran the `sudo ufw allow ssh` from inside the server, and that did it. Problem solved!